# How to manually calculate dffits?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I am trying to replicate what the function dffits() does in R.
I need it for a school project. Can anyone help me?

Sorry, if this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Do you need the concepts and formulas, or are you just looking for `R` code?

Comment: I need the R code, but I have to implement the algorithms by myself. I try it, but i don't get the same values as the function dffits()